# Jenkins Agent stops instantly after starting

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm setting up a docker compose file which starts jenkins, then an agent. I had many errors in my config, so I got a lot of errors when the agent started. Now I fixed them, and I only get this output on my console:

```
jenkins-node-1 exited with code 0
```

When running agent.jar on my local machine, the call is blocking and appears in jenkins. But here it just shuts down. That's my node service so far:

```
node-1:
    image: jenkins/agent
    depends_on:
      jenkins:
        condition: service_healthy
    privileged: true
    container_name: jenkins-node-1
    environment:
      - JENKINS_URL=http://jenkins:8080
      - JENKINS_AGENT_NAME=node-1
    networks:
      - jenkins-net
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: @tkausl Which logs? `docker logs jenkins-node-1` returns nothing, I think nothing fails, it's more like a layer 8 problem

Comment: [seems like you have to configure CMD or entrypoint](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/agent/latest/images/sha256-f0218e7c5d7eb408f3d6a83e37d1b48945ed497a6e849eb904ab064454e1dd0b?context=explore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the command to the docker-compose file to actually call the agent:

```
command: java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins:8080/computer/node%2D1/jenkins-agent.jnlp
```

Answer (score 0):

go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes
examine the node that is running everything

Check in it's configuration to ensure the total # of executors is greater than 0 and that it is online.

Then try redownloading the agent.jar file.

More info on that here:
https://www.edureka.co/community/69051/how-to-increase-no-of-executors-in-jenkins

Comment: Executors is set to 1. Like I said, the agent.jar is running locally fine, but the image just shuts down